# Como mapear classes Java para um formato XML específico?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Estou desenvolvendo um *framework* que gerencia chamadas de sistemas e preciso salvar/carregar o estado das variáveis de instância em um formato XML específico.

Procurei por ferramentas na internet e encontrei o `JAXB 2`. Essa ferramenta permite mapear um `XML Schema` para classes Java, porém eu já possuo as classes e quero fazer uma correspondência um-para-um com o formato XML esperado.

Segue abaixo as três classes do *framework*:

```
public class Experiment {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Task> tasks;

    public Experiment(String name, ArrayList<Task> tasks) {}
    public Experiment(String name, Task ... tasks) {}
}

public class Requirements {
    private int cores;
    private int ram;
    private int storage;
    private long timeout;

    public Requirements(int cores, int ram, int storage, int timeout) {}
}

public class Task implements Runnable {
    private String id;
    private String command;

    private List<Task> dependencies;
    private Requirements requirements;
    private List<Task> observers;

    public Task(String id, String command) {}
}
```

---

Exemplo de um `XML` esperado:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<experiment>
  <name>Test</name>
  <vars>
    <var>
      <id>message</id>
      <value>Hello World!!!</value>
    </var>
    <var>
      <id>string</id>
      <value>String test</value>
    </var>
  </vars>
  <tasks>
    <task>
      <id>print</id>
      <command>echo $(message)</command>
      <dependencies/>
      <requirements>
        <cores>1</cores>
        <ram>0</ram>
        <storage>0</storage>
        <timeout>0</timeout>
      </requirements>
    </task>
  </tasks>
</experiment>
```

`Schema` gerado a partir do exemplo pelo `IntelliJ`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="experiment" type="experimentType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="varType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="id"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="value"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="varsType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="varType" name="var" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="requirementsType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="cores"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ram"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="storage"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="timeout"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="taskType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="id"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="command"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="dependencies"/>
      <xs:element type="requirementsType" name="requirements"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="tasksType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="taskType" name="task"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="experimentType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
      <xs:element type="varsType" name="vars"/>
      <xs:element type="tasksType" name="tasks"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

---

Alguém pode me explicar como faço para converter um objeto `Experiment` para XML e vice-versa?

Comment: Você pode criar seu próprio parse e escrever as tags XML com o nome que quiser.

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/parsers/documentbuilderfactory/create-xml-file-in-java-using-dom-parser-example/

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Já tenho uma solução "manual" como essa, porém é inviável para mim uma vez que a chance de alterações no schema é alta. Não quero ter que mudar código toda vez que uma nova alteração apareça.

Comment: Utilizar anotações ajudaria no seu caso? Por exemplo: https://github.com/marcusbecker/NodeThunder/wiki/Using-annotations

Comment: Fiz isso ontem à noite. Segui o tutorial em http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/example_schemagen_basic.html
Porém estou com um probleminha. Vou fazer uma outra pergunta para tentar resolvê-lo.

Comment: A nova pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/356276/como-anotar-propiedades-java-do-tipo-map-utilizando-o-jaxb2

Comment: Você pode utilizar o Jackson XML parser. Tem este artigo que explica detalhadamente como funciona https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization